# Why language packs have to be loaded before main window is created in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qtranslator

I just learned how to set a language pack for my app in Qt, and I am currently have two questions. I wrote a minimal app to show where confused me.
I created a main window, which only contains a `QLabel` to show text and a `QPushButton` to change label text from Chinese to English.
And here is my code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    chineseTr = new QTranslator;
    chineseTr->load("../untitled/Language-Pack_zh-CN.qm");
    englishTr = new QTranslator;
    englishTr->load("../untitled/Language-Pack_en-US.qm");
    QCoreApplication::installTranslator(chineseTr);

    mWidget = new QWidget;
    setCentralWidget(mWidget);
    hLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    mWidget->setLayout(hLayout);
    mLbl = new QLabel;
    mLbl->setText(tr("Text"));
    translateBtn = new QPushButton;
    connect(translateBtn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::translateText);
    hLayout->addWidget(mLbl);
    hLayout->addWidget(translateBtn);
}

void MainWindow::translateText()
{
    QCoreApplication::removeTranslator(chineseTr);
    QCoreApplication::installTranslator(englishTr);
}
```

**Question One:**
As you can see in the constructor, I loaded the language pack first, or the `QLabel` will just not show Chinese text. I can either load the Chinese language pack before creating everything else in the constructor, or load in `main.cpp` before creating `MainWindow` object. Am I getting this wrong or those language packs just have to be loaded before creating class objects? 
**Question Two:**
As you can see in the code, I clicked the button and to remove the Chinese language pack and install the new translator to load the English language pack. But nothing works. So how can I change language dynamically in the app? I know this question may be simple, but I do not find any useful example online to show me how to do this? So can someone show me a way to do this or give me a hint? 
Hope I explain myself clearly, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to understand *where* translation happens: inside `tr(...)` call. `tr(...)` returns the translated text. Which means, that replacing translator will influence subsequent calls to `tr(...)`, but have no chance to change texts already displayed in widgets.

Easiest way to do "switch language on the fly" is to introduce method containing all `tr(...)` calls and call it after replacing translator and in constructor. I believe that code generated from `.ui` (the ones created by QtDesigner) files already has such method.

```
void MainWindow::translate()
{
     mLbl->setText(tr("Text"));
}

void MainWindow::translateText()
{
    QCoreApplication::removeTranslator(chineseTr);
    QCoreApplication::installTranslator(englishTr);
    translate();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, one more problem, what if I don't have the .ui form and I have more than one widget in different classes, which means I can't call every one of them after changing the language. Then what's the correct way to apply changing language to all the widgets?

Comment: unfortunately that means you have to write that "translate" method in each class and call it from top to down (so MainWindow::translate should call SubWindow::translate etc.)